# firebase.storage() can't be called in iphone

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire, firebase-storage

I'm developing a hybrid app with ionic.
firebase.storage() not working...
please help me..

**Ionic Info**
cli packages: (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.3
Cordova Platforms  : none
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.0
```

System:

```
Node : v6.11.0
npm  : 3.10.10
OS   : Windows 10
```

**My Package.json**
 : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1n9a51UJ3wTGIim3WVbIzhW4_ftYfNJN4

I have developed a user-selected file to be uploaded to the firebase storage as an image.

When the "uploadVerify()" is called from the "login.html" file, 
the file selected by the user changes to blob.

After that, it is stored in storage through "uploadPicture()" function. 
It works well locally(ionic serve in browser), 
but the iPhone does not seem to be able to call the firebase.storage () part.

If there is a way, ask for help. thanks.

```js
import { Component, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { AlertController, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { NavController, MenuController, NavParams, ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { CoolLocalStorage } from 'angular2-cool-storage';
import { SearchPage } from '../search/search';
import { FilterPage } from '../filter/filter';
import { AutoCompletePage } from '../autocomplete/autocomplete';
import { UtilProvider } from '../../providers/util/utils';
import { Ng2ImgToolsService } from 'ng2-img-tools';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth'
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/storage';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})

export class LoginPage {
  storage: CoolLocalStorage; 

  isEnabled = true; isReadonly = true;
  imgFile1; imgName;
  verificationImageURL;

  constructor(public nav: NavController, public menu: MenuController, private modalCtrl: ModalController,
   private navParams: NavParams, public alertCtrl: AlertController, public util: UtilProvider, private ng2ImgToolsService: Ng2ImgToolsService,
    storage: CoolLocalStorage, public http: Http, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController, public afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private afDB: AngularFireDatabase) {
   this.storage = storage;
    
    this.menu.swipeEnable(false);
  }
  uploadVerify(event){
      if(event.target.files && event.target.files[0]){
        let fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
        let file: File = fileList[0];
        if( !file.type.match(/image.*/)){
            this.util.doAlert("error","not image","ok");
            event.target.result = "";
        }else{
            this.ng2ImgToolsService.resize( [file], 400, 400).subscribe(
              result =>{
                this.util.doAlert("imageResize", result,"확인");
                /*
                let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
                  content: 'upload...'
                });
                loading.present();
                */
                this.imgFile1 = new File( [result], result.name);
                this.imgName = Date.parse(new Date().toISOString()).toString();
                this.uploadPicture(this.imgFile1, this.imgName).then(imageUrl =>{
                    if( imageUrl ){
                      this.util.doAlert("uploadedFirebase", imageUrl,"확인");
                      //loading.dismiss();
                      this.verificationImageURL = imageUrl;
                    }else{
                    }
                });
              },
              Error =>{
                console.log('img1 Compression error');
            });
        }
      }
  }
  uploadPicture(file, imageName){
    let email = this.email;
    let promise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
      let fileName = imageName + '.jpg';
      let pictureRef = firebase.storage().ref('/userVerifications/'+email+'/'+fileName);
      let metadata: firebase.storage.UploadMetadata = {
        contentType: 'image/jpeg',
      };
      let uploadTask = pictureRef.put(file, metadata);
      uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED, (snapshot) =>{

      },(error) => {
          rej(error);
      },() => {
          var downloadURL = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
          res(downloadURL);
      });
    });
    return promise;
  }
  }
```